# Is there a function that returns either $0$ or $1$ with the input being either $0$ or $X$

Tags: calculus

I have inputs $x,y$ with values ranging from $0$ to $10000$ and I'm in the need of a way to use this input to deactivate/activate the given input.

Searched for function : $f(x)$

Resulting equation:

$$ g(x,y) = x·f(x) + y·f(y)$$

for $x = 0$:

$$g(0,y) = y$$

for $y = 0$:

$$g(x,0) = x$$

I basically need the function to output $1$ if the variable isn't $0$.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You can use indicator functions for this or Kronecker delta functions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta

Comment: @Florian this sounds like the solution to the problem. Do you have a link to the actual use of these functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Modified Sigmoid Function

$f(x) =\lceil \left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-x}}-0.5\right)\rceil$.  For x = 0, it is 0, for any value of x greater than 0, it will yield 1.

Implementation in EXCEL

=CEILING(1/(1+EXP(-C6)) - 0.5,1)

Goodluck

Comment: Taking this equation times 2 and multiplying x by 1000000 gets me the result I wanted.

Comment: You are welcome!!.  Happy that it works!!

Answer (score 1):

If your input is an integer value between $0$ and $10000$, you could take $f(x) = \min\{1,x\}$.

Answer (score 0):

> $f(0) = 0$ and otherwise $f(x) = 1$

is a perfectly good description of an entirely valid function. If you don't like words, but want just symbols, the standard way would be
$$
f(x) = \cases{0 & if $x = 0$\\1 & otherwise}
$$

Comment: But whats the actual computation behind this? I need to get the actual function, for use in a programming language. I can't use if statements.

Comment: @Phil Well, that's an _entirely_ different question, and will depend greatly on what language you're using. And on some level there _has_ to be an if test for this. If not written explicitly by you, then hidden in the commands you use.

Comment: language is Modelica and I can't use if statements since this is to be used on a continuous signal during simulation. A if statement generates events slowing down the simulation significantly.

Comment: @Phil Well, then this isn't a question you should direct at mathematicians, but a question you should direct at people who know Modelica. However, if $g(0, y) = y$ and $g(x, 0) = x$ is your _only_ requirement, then $g(x, y) = x + y$ ought to do the trick. If, on the other hand, you _need_ an $f$ such that $g(x, y) = xf(x) + yf(y)$, then I think this is your only shot. If you're lucky with how your language deals with $0/0$, you can use $f(x) = x/x$. If not, I suggest you direct your question to stackexchange or something, and say specifically what language you want help in.

Comment: @Phil Some googling leads me to the [`sign()` function](https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/ModelicaReference.Operators.%27sign()%27.html), but it says in the documentation that it is expanded into an if test anyways. As I said, there has to be an if test in there somewhere. You can't get around that.

Comment: @Artuhr x+y works in this case, but I wanted to use this searched for equation for other conditional (ifs..duh) in another part of the code as well. I just thought there is some mathematical trick i could use to archive this.

Answer (score 0):

This is elaborating on Arthur's answer, to make it "a formula" avoiding an "if statement".  If your highest input is $N$, choose a prime number $p$ bigger than $N$ and fix it.

Now the function is $F:\{0,1,2,\ldots, N\}\to \{0,1\}$ is 
$F(x) = x^{p-1}\pmod p$.

This does what you want by Fermat's Little theorem.

But I am not sure this is desirable. A program with a simple if statement will be fast to execute than calculating powers.

Comment: The function is used in a simulation. If statements generate events from which the solver has to recalculate/arrange jacobians.

Answer (score 0):

For the specific interval you have, one such function I can think of is $f(x)= \lfloor (x)^{1/100}\rfloor$.

Comment: $1/14$ in place of $1/100$ works too.